# SaltStack: Do x if /var/log/backup exists

Tags: saltstack, conditional

I want to execute this state:

```
backup_log_readable:
  acl.present:
    - name: /var/log/backup
    - acl_type: user
    - acl_name: monitor
    - perms: rx
    - recurse: True
```

But this should happen only if `/var/log/backup` exists.

How to do conditions like this in salt?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alternatively to the `onlyif: test -d /var/log/backup` approach (that is probably the best one) you can:

**1)** Wrap everything with a jinja if:

```
{%- if salt['file.directory_exists' ]('/var/log/backup') %}
backup_log_readable:
  acl.present:
    - name: /var/log/backup
    - acl_type: user
    - acl_name: monitor
    - perms: rx
    - recurse: True
{%- endif %}
```

**2)** use the `file.exists` state as a requisite:

```
backup_log_exists:
  file.exists:
    - name: /var/log/backup

backup_log_readable:
  acl.present:
    - name: /var/log/backup
    - acl_type: user
    - acl_name: monitor
    - perms: rx
    - recurse: True
    - require:
      - file: backup_log_exists
```

This way you'll see a failed state in the summary, so it won't be totally transparent as with the onlyif and jinja approaches

**3)** create the directory before running the acl state:

```
backup_log_dir:
  file.directory:
    - name: /var/log/backup

backup_log_readable:
  acl.present:
    - name: /var/log/backup
    - acl_type: user
    - acl_name: monitor
    - perms: rx
    - recurse: True
    - require:
      - file: backup_log_dir
```

Comment: I took solution 1 (`{%- if salt['file.directory_exists' ]('/var/log/backup') %}`). Thank you for this answer!

Answer (score 4):

Onlyif should work:

```
- onlyif:
  - test -d /var/log/backup
```

See:
https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#onlyif

Comment: This works. Thank you. I am curious... is there a solution where no subprocess and no shell call is needed?